# DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport and OpenArgs Workaround

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a report used by any report the yields zero records.  The reports title tells what process had zero records.

strNoRecordOpenArg is a Global Veriable

Main Form Code **

```
strNoRecordOpenArg = "Imported AEL's"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_universal_no_records", acFormatPDF, "C:\Reports\Imported AEL's.pdf"
strNoRecordOpenArg = ""
```

Report Code **

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
.txt_header_title.ControlSource = "=""" & strNoRecordOpenArg & """"
End Sub
```

What happens is that the process completes with no report generated.

If I rem out the Report Code it works but the Report Title is #Name.

I use the Immediate window and the value of strNoRecordOpenArg is holding and should be available for the open report process.

All of this is to completely automate the process.  If I use

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_universal_no_records", , "", "", acWindowNormal, "Imported AELs"
```

and use the openarg to feed the report title, everything works but you get prompted to save the file as.

Any Ideas?

Tank you!

Comment: Bueller?... Bueller?... Bueller?... Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on form

```
Dim i As Integer
i = DCount("*", "a_import_aels_step_1")
    If i = 0 Then
        strNoRecordOpenArg = "Imported AEL's"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_universal_no_records", acFormatPDF, "F:\Desktop\Imported AEL's.pdf"
        Exit Sub
```

on report

`Me.txt_header_title.Caption = "" & strNoRecordOpenArg & ""`